# Looking for a good Coding format in Appium-java for Full app testing

Tags: java, testing, appium, hybrid

some doubts regarding Appium Scripting 
1.Scripting i tried above is in a proper way?
 2.After completing the quickpay, i want to do the next scenario so how to redirect to next class for do the next scenario? 
Code i tried is given below
**Base class**

```
   package ********;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;    
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class ************* {
     protected AndroidDriver driver;
        protected WebDriverWait wait;

        //before Test Annotation makes a java function to run every time before a TestNG test case
        @BeforeTest
        protected void createAppiumDriver() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

              DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
              capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "0123456789ABCDEF");
              capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
              capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0");
              capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
              capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "**********);
              capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "********");
              capabilities.setCapability("unicodekeyboard", true);
              capabilities.setCapability("resetkeyboard", true);
              driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);          
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
              wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("android.widget.FrameLayout")));
        }

        //After Test Annotation makes a java function to run every time after a TestNG test case
        @AfterTest
        public void afterTest(){

        //quit the driver
        driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

**Screen class**

```
package **********;

        import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;

        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;


        public class QuickPay extends ************ {
            /*--------------------------------Enter pin Starts---------------------------------*/

             //Enter 4 digit pin to login
             @Test
             public void T4a_Login() {      
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-1')]")).sendKeys("1234");
             } 


        /*--------------------------------Enter pin Ends---------------------------------*/


        /*QuickPay Starts*/

        /*--------------------------------Quick pay to Federal Bank Account starts---------------------------------*/

             //Click on quick pay
             @Test
             public void T5a_QuickpayF() {      
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-30')]")).click();    
             } 

             //Enter account number , Amount and click quick pay
             @Test
             public void T5b_QuickpayF() {      
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'ext-element-229')]")).sendKeys("10015000301404"); 
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'ext-element-236')]")).sendKeys("50"); 
                driver.hideKeyboard();  
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-34')]")).click();
             }

             //Click on confirm button
             @Test
             public void T5c_QuickpayF() {      
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-38') and @index='0']")).click();
             }

             //Enter pin for Quick paya-Federal bank
             @Test
             public void T5d_QuickpayF() {      
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-45') and @index='1']")).click();    
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-46') and @index='2']")).click();
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-47') and @index='3']")).click();
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-48') and @index='4']")).click();
             }

             //Click on home for redirect to Home page
             @Test
             public void T5e_QuickpayF() {  
                 System.out.println("testtt");  
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-60')and @index='0']")).click();
                 System.out.println("rt");
             }



        /*--------------------------------Quick pay to Federal Bank Account Ends---------------------------------*/

        }
```

**PoM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aws.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>appium-android-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.6</version>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
   <properties>
        <appium.version>3.3.0</appium.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Appium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${appium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your test is hard to maintain and to read. You should read about the Page Object Pattern, in short it splits the part of defining the elements that are on the screen of the tested app with the behaviours and checks that you want to perform with this elements.

Basically instead of calling `.findByXPath()` every time (which at point when you will have dozens or hundreds of steps will get hell to maintain), you want to call some methods which describe action you want to achieve f.e. `loginPage.setUsername()` where loginPage is the class where you defined all the elements f.e. `@FindBy(xpath = "//android.some.xpath") MobileElement loginField` and methods `public void setUsername()` This way, when something changes in the app you only change one method in class and not all your tests.

[Appium Example of Page Object](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/Page-objects.md)

[Selenium Best Practice Guide](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/best.html)