# How to get the *-tests.jar for configuring Appium with AWS device farm?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, testing, appium

i was created a maven project in eclipse.A sample code i tried is Working fine in my physical device.For uploading my test cases to AWs console need this          *-tests.jar file. But this file is not creating in my project

**Project Structure is given below**

[image: My project hierarcy is given below]

Source code i tried is also attached below

**Base class**

```
 package ********;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;    
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class ************* {
     protected AndroidDriver driver;
        protected WebDriverWait wait;

        //before Test Annotation makes a java function to run every time before a TestNG test case
        @BeforeTest
        protected void createAppiumDriver() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

              DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
              capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "0123456789ABCDEF");
              capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
              capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0");
              capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
              capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "**********);
              capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "********");
              capabilities.setCapability("unicodekeyboard", true);
              capabilities.setCapability("resetkeyboard", true);
              driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);          
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
              wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("android.widget.FrameLayout")));
        }

        //After Test Annotation makes a java function to run every time after a TestNG test case
        @AfterTest
        public void afterTest(){

        //quit the driver
        driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

**Screen class**

```
     package **********;

        import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;

        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;


        public class QuickPay extends ************ {
            /*--------------------------------Enter pin Starts---------------------------------*/

             //Enter 4 digit pin to login
             @Test
             public void T4a_Login() {      
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-1')]")).sendKeys("1234");
             } 


        /*--------------------------------Enter pin Ends---------------------------------*/


        /*QuickPay Starts*/

        /*--------------------------------Quick pay to Federal Bank Account starts---------------------------------*/

             //Click on quick pay
             @Test
             public void T5a_QuickpayF() {      
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-30')]")).click();    
             } 

             //Enter account number , Amount and click quick pay
             @Test
             public void T5b_QuickpayF() {      
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'ext-element-229')]")).sendKeys("10015000301404"); 
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'ext-element-236')]")).sendKeys("50"); 
                driver.hideKeyboard();  
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-34')]")).click();
             }

             //Click on confirm button
             @Test
             public void T5c_QuickpayF() {      
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-38') and @index='0']")).click();
             }

             //Enter pin for Quick paya-Federal bank
             @Test
             public void T5d_QuickpayF() {      
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-45') and @index='1']")).click();    
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-46') and @index='2']")).click();
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-47') and @index='3']")).click();
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-48') and @index='4']")).click();
             }

             //Click on home for redirect to Home page
             @Test
             public void T5e_QuickpayF() {  
                 System.out.println("testtt");  
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'ext-button-60')and @index='0']")).click();
                 System.out.println("rt");
             }



        /*--------------------------------Quick pay to Federal Bank Account Ends---------------------------------*/

        }

**PoM.xml**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aws.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>appium-android-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.6</version>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
   <properties>
        <appium.version>3.3.0</appium.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Appium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${appium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type :

```
mvn -h
```

You'll get the help page for Maven printed out into the console. Focus on :

```
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

After that try this:

```
mvn -DskipTests package
```

Comment: Yeah its working i tried the following steps  .. Thankzzzz

Comment: nice, happy for that. keep going

Comment: can you please help me for some doubts regarding Appium Scripting

1.Scripting i tried above is in a proper way?

2.After completing the quickpay, i want to do the next scenario so how to redirect to next class for do the next scenario?

Comment: i suggest that u ask a separate question, but to give you a  way try to use testng framework !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886043/looking-for-a-good-coding-format-in-appium-java-for-full-app-testing